# Adding custom control dynamically to Custom Field in Sitecore gives App_Web_xxxx.dll not found

Tags: content-editor, custom-field

I have a created a simple user control and dynamically added that control to a new custom field in Sitecore. When viewing the item having that custom field in content editor, it works just fine. If I click on any other item or even try to save that item I get a popup error saying:

**Could not load file or assembly'file:///G:\SitecoreInetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreInstance\Website\bin\App_Web_test.ascx.cdcab7d2.z3kp1dyl.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

DLL name changes every time I clean build the solution. Also dynamically adding a control creates a temp dll (App_Web_test.ascx.cdcab7d2.z3kp1dyl.dll) in "C:\windows\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder however it is looking for the same in inetpub which it couldn't find.

I am not sure what is causing this.
This is the Custom field class:

```
    public class XMLField : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.File, Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.IContentField
    {
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
            {
                    Test test = (Test)Page.LoadControl("/Test.ascx");
                    test.ID = "TEST_ID";
                    test.Visible = true;
                    Controls.Add(test);
            }
            base.OnLoad(e);
        }


        public new string GetValue()
        {
            return Value;
        }

        public new void SetValue(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            base.Render(output);
        }

        public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
        {
            base.HandleMessage(message);
        }

    }
```

User control Test.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitecoreWebsite.Test" %>
<div id="testdiv">
    Test Div
</div>
```

User control backend Test.ascx.cs

```
    public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should try to add "everyone" permission on your website folder(it´s not recommended on CM and CD servers) but for a developer machine, it can be a way to test (just to make sure if it´s not a lack of permissions).

Comment: Tried it, still the same error.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are you trying to accomplish here? Looking from your code you have created a new custom field in Sitecore and you are loading a control on it's load?
The reason why I ask this is that depending on what you are trying to do the approach to take may differ from what you are taking and get rid of the problem altogether

Comment: @Diego I am trying to create a custom field where one can set a media library path of a file and then view all its content via that user control I have added. I have tried that via Render method and it works fine but just for the sake of modularity and clarity I am creating a separate control to render the html. Hope the purpose is clear now.

Comment: Well,
You can also change your implementation, maybe a Simple ASP NET Repeater,would do the job without errors .

Comment: Did you try cleaning up the temp directories? https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2011/06/01/solving-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app_web_squ1ikqu-version0-0-0-0-cultureneutral-publickeytokennull-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-net-4-0/ - Also I've had issues where security solutions like antivirus prevent the app from accessing the ASP.NET temp folder.

Comment: @maz I tried deleting all temp files and even stopped started app pool but still no luck.